# Excel Do While cell text is true

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet set up like so:

```
Col A
-----
TEXT 1
McCartney, Paul
Lennon, John
Harrison, George
Starr, Ringo
TEXT 2
Lee, Geddy
Lifeson, Alex
Peart, Neil
```

In Column B I want to add text as long as you haven't reached 'TEXT 2' yet. For instance, my data might look like:

```
Col A               Col B
-----               -----
TEXT 1              
McCartney, Paul     Beatles
Lennon, John        Beatles
Harrison, George    Beatles
Starr, Ringo        Beatles
TEXT 2              
Lee, Geddy          Rush
Lifeson, Alex       Rush
Peart, Neil         Rush
```

I tried several combinations of 'Do While' and 'If ... Then... End If', but nothing was working. How do I write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have three 'title' rows in Column A: Open, Gain, and Limited. Those names are static. The number of rows between them is always going to be different. The data between those rows are peoples names in the format 'Last, First'. I'm trying to add a column at the end that says 'Open' when the row is between the 'Open' row and the 'Gain' row. Then I want to put the word 'Gain' in this new column between the 'Gain' and 'Limited' rows. From there down the new column will say 'Limited'. I hope this makes sense. – Mr_Thomas 3 hours ago

Is this what you are trying?

Put this formula in Cell `B1` and copy it down

`=IF(ISNA(INDEX(MATCH("Limited",$A$1:$A1,0 ),1,1)),IF(ISNA(INDEX(MATCH("Gain",$A$1:$A1,0 ),1,1)),IF(ISNA(INDEX(MATCH("Open",$A$1:$A1,0 ),1,1)),"","Open"),"Gain"),"limited")`

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: I read the OP's comment to mean that he wanted to only show the category names between the "title rows", i.e., show a blank in cells B1, B7, and B14 in your example.  One way to achieve this would be by expanding your formula to ' =IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(A1,"opengainlimited"))),"",<your formula>)'

Comment: Ding! Ding! Ding! We have a winner! I wasn't worried about the 'title' row because, once this column was established, those title rows are going to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for this - just put this formula in `B2`:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("TEXT 2",$A$2:A2,1,0)),"Beatles","")
```

and autofill down until the end of data in column `A`.

Comment: All rows in column B end up blank. Also, how does this take into effect 'TEXT 1' and 'TEXT 3'? (where TEXT 3 is further down on Column A).

Comment: @Mr_Thomas check the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ngi72enc9sdnjw/Beatles.xlsx - initial condition: "In Column B I want to add text as long as you haven't reached 'TEXT 2' yet." is met as requested.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing -- and it does work for what it is. However, my original intent was to have something that looped through column A and added a value in column B based on whether the row was still in the 'Beatles' range or if it had changed to 'Rush'.

Comment: @Mr_Thomas you need either provide all separators or at least their pattern - or how they're different from actual data

Comment: I have three 'title' rows in Column A: `Open`, `Gain`, and `Limited`. Those names are static. The number of rows between them is always going to be different. The data between those rows are peoples names in the format 'Last, First'. I'm trying to add a column at the end that says 'Open' when the row is between the 'Open' row and the 'Gain' row. Then I want to put the word 'Gain' in this new column between the 'Gain' and 'Limited' rows. From there down the new column will say 'Limited'. I hope this makes sense.